# How to format f-strings from dataframe with curly brackets in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, f-string

How to format f-strings from dataframe with curly brackets in the dataframe?

Text in a dataframe that has curly brackets `{` and `}` in the text, which is intended to trigger f-string formatting of defined variables in the Python code. But the code instead just yields the actual text like "{From}" instead of the actual name. Below is the code. Thank you for your help.

```
        DocText = DT.loc[(DT['To'] == NameList2) & (DT['From'] == NameList1) & (DT['Type'] == 'Document'), 'Text'].reset_index(drop=True)
        for i in DocText:
                    docap(style='ListNumber1').add_run(f'{i}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f-strings only work for constant strings, like the `f'{i}'` you have above.  If you're reading strings from an I/O source, you can use the string `.format()` method to do the substitution.

```
string = "checking {From} and {To}"
print( string.format( From=123, To=456) )
```

Output:

```
checking 123 and 456
```

Looking further, it looks like you may be expecting the "{From}" string to be substituted with the value of the "From" column.  That doesn't work.  You might be able to simulate that using `.apply`, but we'd need to see more details about what data you have and what you are expecting.

Comment: this is close, if the 'from' and 'to' are column names then you can take each row and convert it into a dict and pass it to format: `string.format( **{"From": 123, "To": 456})`

Comment: Mr. Tim Roberts's suggestion of using .format and its unique syntax instead of f-strings solved the problem. Thank you!!